# What to do when link_to is overriding the css class that I've applied?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a serious issue with using the link_to and image_tag methods and CSS. For whatever reason, I cannot maintain the circular shape of my avatar with CSS that I wrote. When I'm using only the image_tag, it works perfectly. When I use both link_to and image_tag, it turns the image back into a square.

Here is the link

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(current_user.avatar_url(:thumb)), current_user, class: 'round-image-50', title:  "Profile", style: '') %>

.round-image-50 {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  img {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

Can you help me figure out exactly why it's overriding the CSS attributes written for it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to define the class class inside of the image_tag portion of the method block.

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(current_user.avatar_url(:thumb), class: 'round-image-50'), current_user, title:  "Profile", style: '') %>
```